# Httpmodule resend/ recreate request

Tags: c#, httpmodule

I have created an httpmodule that gets user ip information and append credentials to the header based on their IP.  It does this every request though.  I would like to listen for a 401 status response and then run the ip look up and resend the request through.

I have all the pieces in place, i can catch the 401 error, and attach credentials to a header, except i cannot figure out how to resend the request through with the new header.

Possibly transfer or rewrite?

Comment: I'm no expert on httpmodules but I doubt that you can do what you are explaining.  If you are catching the response then the request has obviously been processed.  Your module needs to know up front wether the request will result in a 401 or not, in other words I think you need to do the lookup for every request.

Answer (score 0):

I won't go into details why you've chosen such strategy as this doesn't sound very elegant. Anyway given your requirements I would set two cookies in the response, with authentication expiry date and hash value to validate expiry date. Then change the response to 301 redirect to the same url. Next time the request arrives I has set cookie which you identify/validate and attach the credential headers. Cookies example would be:

```
Set-Cookie: AuthExpiry=20/02/2012T12:30:12
Set-Cookie: AuthHash=38D67A30F9453E6A9A025A2395AC07EA198383A5
```

Where AuthHash is generated by concatenating GetSHA(AuthExpiry+yourSecretPhrase)